# Triggers the azure message queue an event when a message was added? How can I subscribe to? this event?

Tags: azure-storage, message-queue, .net-core

Is it possible to configure a Azure Message Queue so it calls a web request or whatever when a message was added or deleted? Or is the only thing I can do is polling for new messages in the queue?

Answer (score 2):

No. You can actually use Azure Queues to trigger certain events/functions like Azure Webjobs and such. You can find more information about it here:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-storage-queues-how-to/